# JBoss - configuring server.xml Connector

Tags: security, ssl, jboss, ssl-certificate, keystore

I've configured HTTP Connector in server.xml adding some ssl features. I tryied to set my keyAlias to  which is the name of the alias for certain certificate (not the private key of the keystore). Then, when I start JBoss I get something like:

```
[2012-04-12 17:01:37,236 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] Error 
initializing endpoint
java.io.IOException: Alias name <somealias> do not indetify a key entry
```

I'm new to ssl configuration and web security core concepts as well. Thanks for your patience.

Edit: complete stacktrace follows:

```
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:412)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:378)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:135)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:514)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1146)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb.startConnectors(JBossWeb.java:601)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.JBossWeb.handleNotification(JBossWeb.java:638)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.mx.notification.NotificationListenerProxy.invoke(NotificationListenerProxy.java:153)
at $Proxy46.handleNotification(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.mx.util.JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.handleNotification(JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:127)
at org.jboss.mx.util.JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.sendNotification(JBossNotificationBroadcasterSupport.java:108)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.sendNotification(ServerImpl.java:916)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:497)
at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:508)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: What are you setting the alias to ? Does the other private key exist in the keystore ?

Comment: That's the point I think, the information summoned, when I access certificate info in the browser, is related to the private key, but it should be related to the certificate (we have obtained both trial root and intermediate certificates from verisign).

Comment: I must add that I generated the keystore through keytool in Ubuntu, it  states that a key-pair is created inside the keystore (both public and private).

Comment: The alias has to point to a valid key.

Comment: That's true, I've just realized that the key you summon in keyAlias must have at least a private-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not importing your keys properties. I'd recommend you review your steps against these two documents

```
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html
```

A shorter version is here

```
http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html
```